# Usage listview tool : select a value on ListView

Tags: c#, .net, list, listview

```
if (this.listView2.Items[0].Selected == true)
{
    SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand("Update Friend set Tik = 1  Where Email = '"
        + listView2.SelectedItems[0].Text
        + "' and FriendID = "
        + int.Parse(Form2.xxx.ToString()), cnn);
    cnn.Open();
    int gg = cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Arkadaşlık İsteği Onaylandı.");
    cnn.Close();
}
```

What can I use to select a selected value on `ListView`?

```
        SqlCommand xcx = new SqlCommand("Select * From Friend Where Tik = 0 and Email ='" + **listView2.SelectedItems[0].Text** + "'", cnn);
```

Or in this query. how can i use it. i click the listview item which selected. and i want to take the value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `SelectedItems[0]` won't work in your case (I think it should) you can use inherited [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property also..

As Selam22 [pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732094/usage-listview-tool-select-a-value-on-listview#comment34645738_22732140), there is no `.Text` property for `SelectedItems`. You can use `Item` property which returns `object`. Then you can use `.ToString()` method. Like;

```
listView2.SelectedItems[0].Item.ToString()
```

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand("Update Friend set Tik = 1 Where Email = @email and FriendID = @id)", cnn);
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", listView2.SelectedItems[0].Item.ToString());
cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(Form2.xxx.ToString()));
cnn.Open();
int gg = cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Arkadaşlık İsteği Onaylandı.");
cnn.Close();
```

We don't see your connection code you defined but consider to use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

Comment: SelectedItems.Text ? there is no such property on `SelectedItems`

Comment: @Selman22 Then why you used `SelectedItems` in your answer if there is no such a property?

Comment: I mean,there is no `Text` property.It's (SelectedItems) a collection of items. not a single item.

Comment: @Selman22 Yeah, there is no `.Text` property for `SelectedItems`. Instead, `.Item` property can be easly use in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
int EmailColumnIndex = 2; //it is the column index of Email column in ListView
ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection items = listView1.SelectedItems;
ListViewItem item = items[0];
string selctedEmail = item.SubItems[EmailColumnIndex].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
listView2.SelectedItems.Count > 0
```

instead of:

```
this.listView2.Items[0].Selected == true
```